# Rails - How to use the 'has_secure_password' technique for emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

Rails 3.1.0 - Ruby 1.8.6

I'm trying to create a signup page. I came across this 'has_secure_password' with basically does all the magic for you to enter your password twice and checks if they are correct.

I'd like to use this technique to check on email address as well. If it's not possible, what is the easiest way for me to get the user to key in their email twice and check if they match?

Please help. I'm a rails noob.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails has a `validates_confirmation_of` validation built in. If your model has

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessor :email_confirmation
   validates_confirmation_of :email
end
```

Then you just need an email confirmation text field in your form and rails will check that they match.